# How many ways are there to get 8 balls of all 3 colors?

Tags: generating-functions, balls-in-bins

A box contains $7$ distinct red marbles, $6$ distinct green marbles and $5$ distinct yellow marbles.  How many ways are there to get $8$ balls of all $3$ colors, at least one of each color and that order doesn't matter ?

My attempt :
This is my generating function :
Sage:

$f= (x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24+x^5/120)*(x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24+x^5/120+x^6/720)*(x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24+x^5/120+x^6/720+x^7/7!)$

My answer: $5740$. Unfortunately, this is the wrong answer.

Can someone help me to find the correct answer?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you require at least one ball of each color?  I don't think it is clear.  Does it matter what order you draw the balls in?  I don't think so.  Without clear answers the problem is not well specified.

Comment: I would do it by inclusion exclusion.  Suppose each ball is different (number them, say).  Then there are $\binom {18}8$ unordered ways to choose eight of them, and these are all equally probable.  Now subtract off that have no red, those that have no yellow, and those that have no green.  Note that it is not possible to be missing two colors (why?).

Comment: Note:  I am assuming that you want at least one of each color and that order doesn't matter, but I agree that you should clarify these points.

Comment: Should say, your answer seems far too small...are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?  $\binom {18}8=43758$ and the exclusions are pretty minor so the answer will be pretty close to that.

Comment: Must this problem be solved, using generating functions?

Comment: Yes sir, using GF.

Comment: ...marbles of the same color to be different too.

Comment: I think that the GF for marbles of the same color to be identical is $x^3(1-x^5)(1-x^6)(1-x^7)(1-x)^{-3}$

Comment: No, eg if there are $3$ distinct red marbles, your term for red marbles would be $\left[\binom31x +\binom32x^2 + \binom33x^3\right]$

Comment: Correct answer :41811

Comment: @true blue anil: specially thank you very much. Thank for all responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each red marble is said to be **distinct**, same with green and yellow, you need to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the expression

$[(7 x + 21 x^2 + 35 x^3 + 35 x^4 + 21 x^5 + 7 x^6 + x^7) (6 x + 15 x^2 + 20 x^3 + 15 x^4 + 6 x^5 + x^6) (5 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 5 x^4 + x^5)]$

which comes to be $41811$

[ You have to **choose** the marbles from each color in the function, and use an $OGF$ ]

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: Thank you mille fois. BTW, What's the situation (case) for using my generating function above ? (Sorry my bad English!)

Comment: @OGFandEGF: It is for *permutations* of $8$ balls chosen from $7$ *identical* red marbles, $6$ *identical* green marbles and $5$ *identical* yellow marbles.

Comment: Thank you again.